# find duplicates value with their keys

Tags: php, arrays

My array is like this,

```
$options = Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 180
            [label] => Nokia
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 2341
            [label] => Suisses
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 143
            [label] => Nokia
        )
     [3] => Array
        (
            [value] => 2389
            [label] => 3D Pop Art 
        )
    )
```

and i want output as,

```
Array(
[0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 180
            [label] => Nokia
        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 143
            [label] => Nokia
        )
)
```

Can anyone suggest me in this.

Comment: And your approach?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948946/php-check-for-duplicate-values-in-a-multidimensional-array <- this helps ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Check for duplicate values in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948946/php-check-for-duplicate-values-in-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$options = [
    0 => [
            'value' => 180,
            'label' => 'Nokia'
        ],

    1 => [
            'value' => 2341,
            'label' => 'Suisses'
        ],

    2 => [
            'value' => 143,
            'label' => 'Nokia'
        ],
     3 => [
            'value' => 2389,
            'label' => '3D Pop Art'
        ],
];

$labels = [];
$duplicates = [];
foreach ($options as $option) {
    if (!empty($duplicates[$option['label']])) {
        $duplicates[$option['label']][] = $option;
    }

    if (empty($labels[$option['label']])) {
        $labels[$option['label']] = $option;
    } else {
        $duplicates[$option['label']] = [
            $labels[$option['label']],
            $option
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for group by 'label'

```
 foreach($options as $v){
  $c[$v['label']][] = $v['value'];
 }
 print_r($c);
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/62dv0

Answer (score 0):

The `array_filter()` function is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$data = [
    [
        'value' => 180,
        'label' => "Nokia"
    ],
    [
        'value' => 2341,
        'label' => "Suisses"
    ],
    [
        'value' => 143,
        'label' => "Nokia"
    ],
    [
        'value' => 2389,
        'label' => "3D Pop Art"
    ]
];
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$output) {
    $output[$entry['label']][] = $entry;
});

print_r(
    array_filter(
        $output, 
        function($entry) {
            return count($entry) > 1;
        }
    )
);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [Nokia] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 180
                    [label] => Nokia
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 143
                    [label] => Nokia
                )

        )
)
```

That output slightly differs from the one suggested by you. But it has the advantage that you can tell entries apart by the doubled label.